# Preserve data in Angular forms integrated with local bank payment gateway

Tags: angular, .net-core, payment-gateway

Angular form is built and it works well. The form is public and no authentication is required. Before the final submit, fees must be collected through a payment gateway of a local bank and therefore the user is taken to an external page where the payment is processing.

I do not have problems posting the initial required data to the bank API, but how I can return to the from upon process completion (redirect) while the from data are preserved? What is the best practice and what techniques I need to use? Any examples or references are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
localStorage.setItem('dataSource', this.formData);

this.formDataFromLocalStorage= localStorage.getItem('dataSource');
```

Comment: There are many security concerns in using LocalStorage, data may be get exposed. Any other way?

Comment: You store the data in encrypted format or you can use the session storage where the data would be stored for the current session only.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, not just code example )